# Gracefully shutting down USB disk drives before disconnect

Tags: linux, hard-disk, usb-drive

With Fedora 27, when disconnecting an external USB disk drive the journal records lines like these:

```
May 07 22:29:11 usb 2-3.1: USB disconnect, device number 23
May 07 22:29:11 sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
May 07 22:29:11 sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed:
                            Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
```

What is one supposed to do about this?

why does the system/kernel tries to synchronize the cache after the drive is already disconnected?

Is it possible to gracefully shutdown the USB disk before the disconnect? For example with a command that issues the Synchronize-Cache command and then spins down the drive.

This would perhaps also reduce mechanical stress on the drive as the sudden power-loss with spinning disk isn't necessarily optimal.

**Edit:** An `eject /dev/sdb` is ineffective, i.e. the above kernel messages still show up on device unplug and the disk keeps spinning. Instead the eject command yields these kernel log messages:

```
May 18 17:26:06  ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
May 18 17:26:06  Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
May 18 17:26:06   sdb: unable to read partition table
May 18 17:26:06  ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
May 18 17:26:06  Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
May 18 17:26:06   sdb: unable to read partition table
```

**Edit:** Powering the disk down with `udisksctl power-off --block-device /dev/sdb` does work:

```
May 19 08:08:21  udisksd[9447]: Successfully sent SCSI command SYNCHRONIZE CACHE 
                                to /dev/sdb
May 19 08:08:21  udisksd[9447]: Successfully sent SCSI command START STOP UNIT
                                to /dev/sdb
May 19 08:08:21  kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
May 19 08:08:21  udisksd[9447]: Powered off /dev/sdb - successfully wrote
         to sysfs path /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-3/2-3.1/remove
May 19 08:08:21  kernel: usb 2-3.1: USB disconnect, device number 60
```

And indeed, the disk then powers down.

Comment: Oh noes, they messed up the kernel again. File a bug.

Comment: Using the `eject` command should do the trick.  It's not just for optical drives, but for any removable media.

Comment: @TimKennedy, a `eject /dev/sdb` is ineffective, cf. the output in the updated question.

Comment: `/dev/sdb` is the device as a whole, not necessarily the filesystem.  The filesystem is probably `/dev/sdb1` or something.  `lsblk` can identify the filesystems for you.  Then you'd need to `eject /dev/sdb1` (or whatever partition is your filesystem)

Comment: @TimKennedy, actually the disk doesn't have any partitions; the complete device is luks-encrypted; and inside the luks-device there is just one big filesystem and no partition table

Comment: what kernel do you have?  Also, do you get the same messages with other usb block devices?

Comment: @TimKennedy Kernel is 4.15.17-300.fc27.x86_64, yes, I get this with other USB disks/enclosures, as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `udisksctl` to power off the drive:

```
   power-off
       Arranges for the drive to be safely removed and powered off. On the OS side this includes ensuring that
       no process is using the drive, then requesting that in-flight buffers and caches are committed to stable
       storage. The exact steps for powering off the drive depends on the drive itself and the interconnect
       used. For drives connected through USB, the effect is that the USB device will be deconfigured followed
       by disabling the upstream hub port it is connected to.
```

so e.g.

```
udisksctl power-off --block-device /dev/sdb
```

You can run the command as a regular user, no need for root access.
If you prefer a gui, `gnome disks` has a button to *"power off this disk"*.

Comment: This works, cf. my updated answer. When the `udisks2` isn't running, I assume that the sequence `sdparm --command=sync /dev/sdb` then `sdparm --command=stop /dev/sdb` or `sg_start --stop /dev/sdb` and finally `echo 1 >  /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-3/2-3.1/remove` yields the same results. Perhaps the sync is superfluous as the last step also triggers 'Synchronizing SCSI cache' message. Similarly, the stop command doesn't really stop the device, while the last step does. Thus, perhaps the echoing to '/sys/devices/.../remove` is sufficient.